# Como fazer um INSERT de múltiplas rows, onde algumas rows terão menos valores do que colunas

Tags: sql, db2

Vou tentar dar um exemplo simples do meu problema.

Tenho as seguintes colunas numa tabela chamada "Teste":

> Nome | Idade | Sexo | Nota1 | Nota2 | Nota3

Desejo inserir múltiplas linhas na tabela, porém nem todos os alunos terão todas as notas. Exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO "Teste" ("Nome", "Idade", "Nota1", "Nota2", "Nota3") VALUES("Caio","19", 10, 9, 8), ("João","17", 10, 9);
```

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de fazer essa inserção.

OBS: Eu poderia botar `null` ou uma string vazia(`" "`), mas não posso.

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Alguém poderia, por exemplo, ter as notas 2 e 3 mas não ter a 1?

Comment: Sim. Os alunos podem ter 1 das 3, nenhuma e assim por diante.

Comment: Se a nota faltante pode ser qualquer uma das três não vejo como você informar tal situação sem ser não informando o(s) campo(s) correspondente(s) à(s) nota(s) inexistente(s) na lista de campos ou informando NULL na lista de valores no(s) valor(es) correspondente(s) à(s) nota(s) faltante(s). Não há como o SGBD saber sem você informar explicitamente.

Comment: Então não há como fazer oq eu quero?

Answer (score 1):

Não há uma sintaxe para inserir linhas múltiplas, onde uma linha afete determinados campos, e outra linha afete outros campos.

Cada INSERT deverá especificar as colunas a serem inseridas, e todos os valores se referirão àquelas colunas.

No fundo, para que cada linha se referisse a campos diferentes, teríamos que explicar a cada linha o que deve ser feito, então no fundo isto se reduz ao problema de fazer um INSERT para cada situação. Sendo que neste caso, concordo que há uma simplificação, pois as colunas a não serem inseridas seriam sempre as últimas, então seria como enviar uma lista de valores mais curta. De qualquer forma, não é possível.

Porém, a restrição de que não pode enviar NULL ou string vazia não faz muito sentido. Pois, se o banco de dados aceitasse informar menos colunas no INSERT, significaria que as outras colunas receberiam um valor default, ao ser inserido o registro no banco de dados. Normalmente este valor seria NULL, mesmo, então por que não colocá-lo no próprio INSERT?

Talvez uma outra solução seria renormalizar o banco de dados para ter, de um lado, os atributos da pessoa numa tabela, contendo nome e idade. E, noutra tabela, a descrição da nota ('Nota 1', 'Nota 2'), etc e seu valor, além da identificação do aluno. Assim as notas poderiam ser inseridas somente quando disponiveis.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. No final tive que reestruturar o banco de dados com algumas regras diferentes. Mas até agora não entendi no que eu errei haha, mas vamos aprendendo com o tempo... Obrigado!